# Wrapping a FOR function

Tags: python, wrapper

A python wrapper specifically for `for-loop`s and its actions

I write a lot FOR loops that are, well, pretty generic.

For eg:

```
for x in y:
    do something
```

... and error-prone. eg forgetting the ":", or indentation probs.

Could we put the FOR loop in a def, and call it, supplying it with the something?
An interesting exercise if nothing else.

A basic wrapper...

```
def wrapper(func,*args):
    def wrapped():
        return func(*args)
    return wrapped
wrapper(print,"bob")
wrapper()

...which works. ie prints bob out
```

but I don't know how to make the below work - returning a FOR function made lots of syntax errors.

eg something like:

```
def for_1(y, do_something):
    def wrapped():
        return for x in y:
                  do_something
    return wrapped
for_1(range(3),print("bob\n"))
for_1()
```

...and didn't see bob on the screen 3 times.

Could someone point me in the right direction, please? A wrapper is not doing the returned function.
Perhaps use a class for the wrapper? Then have my own methods(??)
...or maybe point me to someone's page who has done this before. I have explored wrappers and decorators but not seen something for passing parameters to a FOR loop function

Comment: Honestly, if indentation and `:` are a problem here, they are a problem everywhere you are writing python code!

Comment: @DraftVader where are we with this question?

Answer (score 1):

Why make it complicated?

```
def for_1(y, to_print):
    for x in range(y):
      print(to_print)

for_1(3, "bob")
```

OUTPUT:

```
bob
bob
bob
```

EDIT:

```
def square(x):
    print(x*x)


def for_1(y, command, param):
    for x in range(y):
      command(param)

for_1(1, square, 3)
```

OUTPUT:

```
9
```

Comment: Hi user5173426
thankyou for your comments.
I want to make it complicated so that 
a) I learn things,
b) I want to do (many) other things than print.

Comment: @DaftVader You don't have to complicate things in order to learn, infact breaking down the bigger picture into smaller chunks always helps. I added a little customization in my answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply restructure your code to not `return` too early and not call to early.

For this split up the function and parameters as two parameters to your for_1 wrapper. 
If you want return value, gather them in your for loop and return them as a list.

```
def for_1(y, do_something, with_param):
    for x in y:
        do_something(with_param)     

for_1(range(3), print, "bob")
```

Comment: AWESOME, thank you Mailerdaimon :)
That fits what I am trying to, and nudged me in the right direction

for1(EarthPopulation,GiveMe, "$1")

Answer (score 0):

the print is evaluated immediately and its return value passed in. what you want here is to pass in a callable, and append () to the do_something inside the loop. than you can use lambda for the passed in function.

```
def for_1(y, do_something):
    def wrapped():
        return for x in y:
                  do_something() # so we call whatever is passed in to be executed at this point
    return wrapped
f = for_1(range(3),lambda: print("bob\n"))
f()
# or equivalent:
def print_bob():
     print("bob\n")
for_1(range(3),print_bob)
```

Comment: Hi Blues, thank you for your answer. I was just reading about lambda this evening and had similar ideas